# Color change in beamer at R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, presentation, beamer

Esteemed,

I'm having trouble putting together a beamer presentation. I would like to put the title, the footer and the items in green tones.

### I appreciate any help.

```
title: "long title"
date: "10/10/2020"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title[short title]{"long title"}}
  - \AtBeginDocument{\author[author1; author2; author3; author4]{author1\\author2\\author3\\author4}}
  - \addtobeamertemplate{headline}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=2cm,page=2]{img.png}}
 
---
# Introduction   

* text1;  

* text2;  
 
* text3;

* text4.
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should do it.  You can use the `\definecolor` function in the `xcolor` package to define named colors that can be used in `setbeamercolor` and `setbeamertemplate` declarations.   I didn't have the image you were trying to include, so I removed that line from the code below.  I'm also not sure what footer you are talking about.

```
---
title: "long title"
date: "10/10/2020"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
  theme: "CambridgeUS"
keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title[short title]{"long title"}}
  - \AtBeginDocument{\author[author1; author2; author3; author4]{author1\\author2\\author3\\author4}}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \definecolor{olive}{rgb}{0.3, 0.4, .1}
  - \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=olive}
  - \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=green}
  - \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=green}
  - \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{green}$\blacktriangleright$}
  - \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{green}$\blacktriangleright$}


---


# Introduction   

* text1;  

* text2;  

* text3;

* text4.
```

There are a couple of useful resources [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations) identifies a number of different elements whose colors can be set with the `setbeamercolor` declaration.   I also made use of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87133/changing-the-color-of-itemize-item-in-beamer) in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @DaveArmstrong. Their advice's is very useful. Themes like "Madrid", for example, generate a footer with the short names of the authors, title and date. Can I keep that footer in green too?

Comment: @VeltonSousa have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350827/different-parts-of-footer-in-different-colors-in-beamer) which discusses changing the footline color in themes that use the `infolines` package.